# How to keep 'use client' at the top of the code in Vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, prettier

I am looking to use the NextJs app directory. For client-side components, it requires the statement `'use client'` at the top of the file. Vs Code moves this statement from the top of the file to after the import statements.

The command `// prettier-ignore` does not stop it from moving.

How do I stop Vs Code / prettier from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making use of `trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports` to sort the import state. This is a bug from the older version (not sure how old it is. Mine used to be 3.3.0, and I also ran into the same issue).
You will need to update to newer version over this [fix](https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports/pull/186).

Answer (score 0):

By adding "use client" to the top of the importOrder preferences in a prettier config you can keep it at the top. Here is an example of my  prettier.config.cjs file:

```
/** @type {import('prettier').Config} */
module.exports = {
  endOfLine: "lf",
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: false,
  tabWidth: 2,
  trailingComma: "es5",
  importOrder: [
    "use client",
    "^(react/(.*)$)|^(react$)",
    "^(next/(.*)$)|^(next$)",
    "<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>",
    "",
    "^types$",
    "^@/types/(.*)$",
    "^@/config/(.*)$",
    "^@/lib/(.*)$",
    "^@/hooks/(.*)$",
    "^@/components/ui/(.*)$",
    "^@/components/(.*)$",
    "^@/styles/(.*)$",
    "^@/app/(.*)$",
    "",
    "^[./]",
  ],
  importOrderSeparation: false,
  importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
  importOrderBuiltinModulesToTop: true,
  importOrderParserPlugins: ["typescript", "jsx", "decorators-legacy"],
  importOrderMergeDuplicateImports: true,
  importOrderCombineTypeAndValueImports: true,
  plugins: [
    "@ianvs/prettier-plugin-sort-imports",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss",
  ],
}
```